# Get the Jenkins freestyle project code/config

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am using enterprise Jenkins (mean I don't have any option to deploy plug-in).

My question is how we can get pipeline script or config in xml format of a freestyle project or print the code executing in a freestyle project.

My interest is about **invoking downstream projects** when current job is successfully built.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Jenkins server then you can check XML job configuration in `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${PATH_TO_YOUR_JOB}/config.xml`.

If you are interested in learning how to trigger a downstream job within a freestyle project, then you can [check out this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRY05FckpaY).